# Unable to click on Bootstrap model dialog while using fullPage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullpage.js

When I click on the button a **Bootstrap model dialog box** shows but it is unclickable no matter what I do.
I am using **Bootstrap** and **fullPage.js**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obEOzO

```
<body>
<div id="fullpage">
 <div class="section">
 <div class="container">
  <h1> First Page</h1>
</div>
</div>
<div class="section">
<div class="container">
  <h1>Modal Example</h1>

  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" style="position:relative;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#fullpage').fullpage(
{
  sectionsColor: ['#f2f2f2', '#4BBF33']
});
});
 </script>
```

Please help i am stuck in the middle of a project..

Comment: `modal-backdrop` is covering the whole page for some reason. Looking around I found [this](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16148) discussion. There are plenty workarounds now that you know what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the use of the css3 `translate3d` property over the fullpage.js wrapper.

I found 3 solutions for it:

- Set the position of the modal to `fixed` and move the modal outside the plugin's container.
- Use the fullpage.js option `scrollBar:true`, this way the page will scroll in the same way a normal website does (firing the scroll event)
- Use `css3:false`, although this way the plugin won't work as fluid (which is even more noticeable in mobile devices)

I would go for the 1st solution: usin a fixed position for the modal.
You can do it with CSS:

```
.fp-enabled .modal{
   position:fixed !important;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">....</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

[Example online](http://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/dGmbdv)

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
<div class="modal">...</div>

<div id="fullpage">
     <div class="section">...</div>
     <div class="section">...</div>
     <div class="section">...</div>
</div>
```

The modal element does not have to be defines in so much child of the fullpage (fullpage class).
He has to be for the same level (fullpage class) or the superior

@source : https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/192#issuecomment-40346380